# Should this heating system bypass valve be open during operation?

Tags: heating, water-heater

My son recently purchased a home with a hot water heating system. Unfortunately I'm not there to take better pictures. It is based on a Buderus Gas Heater. There appears to be a bypass line with a valve between the cold-in and hot-out lines as you can see in the first picture. Should this be open during opration?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best bet would be to look up who installed it (there should be permit records, at least), and ask them why it's there, and your question. It's a small bypass (I'm guessing 1/2" on 1" pipes, so about 1/4 the capacity) but why it's there at all is not obvious. A **thermostatic** version to maintain boiler return temperature is common enough, a straight-up ball valve between the two is indeed odd.

Comment: I'm no plumber, but it seems sketchy to me to have that tank simply hanging off the copper plumbing without any additional support. Maybe it's fine, but if it were mine, I'd figure out some sort of method of supporting the tank from below or at least the pipes from above.

Comment: I DK about the valve, it might be there for some sort of balancing between feed and return.  But I  hate to say it but I see at least 2 other issues there:  1) there is unprotected wiring cable lower than 8', that's not NEC compliant.  2)  It appears that the copper fittings are directly connected with what appears to be steel (red pipes).   That leads to electrolysis which eventually destroys the connection and it fails. All connections between steel and copper should have dielectric couplings.